# To purge or not to purge

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, mysql

Ubuntu 20.04

Recently on a new machine with a fresh install of **ubuntu 20.04** I installed  mysql server as follows:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

This installed **mysql 8.0** successfully. However, for reasons that aren't germane to my question I need to uninstall **mysql 8.0** and install **mysql 5.7**.

My question is whether I should remove and purge **mysql 8.0** or simply remove it? My concern is that in purging it, I might remove a lib or package dependency that is needed outside of mysql. My understanding is that if I did this:

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server
```

this will uninstall but not remove the configuration files. And if I do this:

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server
```

It will uninstall and purge all the entailed packages from the system.

So my question is, what is the best approach to uninstall **mysql 8.0** and facilitate installing **mysql 5.7** on this ubuntu 20.04 system? As I understand it, installing **mysql 5.7** is somewhat of an adventure in itself. But first step is getting **mysql 8.0** safely out of the way.

Any advice or guidance from those of you more experienced than I in these matters would be most appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: APT is responsible of maintaining dependencies required by other packages, LeoLopez's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```sh
sudo apt remove --purge --auto-remove mysql-server
```

Comment: Thanks @LeoLopez. This removed all related packages and completed successfully. What remains are 3 empty directories: /var/lib/mysql, /var/lib/mysql-files, /var/lib/mysql-keyring. The dates on these match the original install of mysql8 so seem as though they are a result of the original install. Also remaining is a directory  /etc/mysql//conf.d which has files: debian.cnf, my.cnf, my.cnf.fallback. The dates on this stuff does not match the original install. Also looking in /etc/passwsd I see an entry for mysql. Is it important to remove this stuff as well? I need to install mysql 5.7. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to remove the user, because, the new version will create it again. If you are doing the installation manually, then you can remove all remains files.